# Share data through a request lifecycle in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In Spring MVC I can use ThreadLocal to share data between different components through a request, and the data will be automatically cleared when the request is fulfilled. With WebFlux, since a request can be handled by multiple threads, this solution will not work. How to implement a similar solution so that initially a WebFilter can set some data in the request context, then the data can be accessed and modified in the controllers, and any event handlers that the request has gone through?

I tried subscriberContext but it did not work. Here is my code. Why this does not work? Is there another way to share the data?

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> {
        return Mono.subscriberContext()
         .map(context -> {
              context.hasKey("test"); // this returns false
         })
    }

    return Mono.subscriberContext()
        .map(context -> {context.put("test", "test");})
        .flatMap(chain.filter(exchange))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, it is because of `.beforeCommit()`. This Mono and the filter Mono do not share the same `Subscriber`.

To add the value, to the subscriberContext of the request. Try this:

```
chain.filter(exchange)
  .subscriberContext(context -> context.put("KEY", "VALUE"));
```

You can also share values in `ServerWebExchange` attributes. This is Spring Web Flux not Reactor though. For example:

```
exchange.getAttributes().put("KEY", "VALUE");
```

Now, anywhere in your application where you have access to `ServerWebExchange` you can access the attribute using

```
exchange.getAttributes().get("KEY");
```